# Trying to manage state with react inside functions and can't get the state on the function

Tags: reactjs, state

So I'm trying to call a function but is getting the last state and not the new state that I'm sending, the thing is that I want first to call plateLastDigit() update the state then extracDay() and also update the state. then execute the conditionalResponse() with the new states values but is not happening, I'm getting the old values of the `enter code here`state, I know that is because it has to wait for the handle submit to finis executing and then the state will update but I need to have an answer on the jsx once the handlesubmit is over.

```
const Predictor = () => {
    const[plateNumber , setplateNumber] = useState("");
    const[date , setDate] = useState("")
    const[hour , setHour] = useState("")

    const handleSubmit = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        plateLastDigit();
        extracDay();
        conditionalResponse();
    }

    const plateLastDigit = ()=>{
     let fullPlate = plateNumber.split("");
     let lastDigit = fullPlate.pop();
     return setplateNumber(lastDigit);
    }

    const extracDay = ()=>{
      let pattern = /(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/;
        let dt = new Date(date.replace(pattern, "$3-$2-$1"));
        let day = dt.getDay();
        return setDate(day);
        
    }
    console.log("numero de matricula:" , plateNumber , " fecha" , date , " hour ", hour);

    const conditionalResponse = ()=>{
      console.log("Dentro de la funcion conditionalResponse: ", plateNumber, " ", date);
      if(plateNumber === 3 && date === 1){
        return document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "you can't take your car for a spin"
      }else{
        return document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "you can take your car for a spin"
      }
    }
   

  return ( 
    <div className="mt-4">
      <h4>Please enter the inputs required</h4>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group mt-4">
          <label>Plate number:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter your plate number like GXA-0103"
            maxLength="8"
            id="plateNumber"
            name={plateNumber}
            onChange={(event)=> setplateNumber(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Date:</label>
          <input
            type="date"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter the date"
            id="date"
            name={date}
            onChange={(event)=> setDate(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Hour:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter an hour like 7:00"
            id="hour"
            name={hour}
            onChange={(event)=> setHour(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <div id="response"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
  
};
```

Comment: State doesn't work like you think it does. State updates only happen on re-render. Don't treat them like they're synchronous

Comment: Thanks, @JMadelaine, how you suggest I should approach the problem I'm having so I can get the result I whant, which is rendering in the jsx response tag the result depending on the condition.

Comment: Thanks, I solve it,  I use the useEffect hook and pass it a boolean value and then make the function call. But what you said really help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the response with `document.getElementById("response").innerHTML` isn't working as when that method is called, the state hasn't been updated yet.

You should instead enter optional text in the response div, which will be auto-updated when the state changes upon re-render.